# Find classes in package that does not implement superclass

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse  2019-09 (4.13.0). I have a project structure as followed.

```
--package1
----SuperClass.java
--package2
-----subpackage1
-------Class1.java
-------Class2.java
----subpackage2
-------Class3.java
-------Class4.java
```

All the classes in `package2` should implement the superclass `SuperClass.java`.

I know that i can search for all the classes that use `SuperClass.java`, but I want to find the classes that does not implement it and complete these classes.

Is there a way to find all the classes in package `package2` that does NOT implement this superclass?

Comment: This seems like an uncommon need. You can't look at the subclasses of SuperClass and then just open every class that is not in that list?

Comment: My problem is that there are not 4 classes but more than 100 classes which should use this specific superclass. It would be more easier to find the classes that does not use the `SuperClass.java` than to look over 100 classes that implement this superclass.

Comment: I would try an advanced search (CTRL+H) and search a regex within all *.java files. Like `class .* extends (?!SuperClass)`. If you manage to find them you could even use the replace functionality to automatically add `extends SuperClass` where required. That being said that's indeed a strange need.

Comment: @EmmanuelChebbi: Your solution will show me only the classes that implement another superclass than `SuperClass` but not the classes with no superclass (that means with the default superclass `java.lang.Object`)

Comment: @alea That's `class .*(?! extends SuperClass)` or to handle whitespace `class\s+.*(?!\s+extends\s+SuperClass)`.

Comment: My regex was indeed not accurate: my main goal was to propose an approach. Thanks @howlger for suggesting a better one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was thinking about this problem and solved it via a junit test. This has the advantage that this will be executed, when I run all my unit-tests and not when I use the search function. The used reflection libary is [org.reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections)

```
@Test
public void testClasses() throws Exception {
    final List<ClassLoader> classLoadersList = new LinkedList<>();
    classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.contextClassLoader());
    classLoadersList.add(ClasspathHelper.staticClassLoader());

    final Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder().setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(false), new ResourcesScanner())
            .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(classLoadersList.toArray(new ClassLoader[] {})))
            .filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder().include(FilterBuilder.prefix("package2"))));

    // Get all classes which are subtypes of object. This will not get the classes of SuperClass
    final Set<Class<? extends Object>> allObjectClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);

    // A list of allowed classes that are in this package and not implementing SuperClass
    final List<Class<? extends Object>> allowedClasses = Arrays.asList();

    // Get the class names and ignoring the classes in the allowed classes
    final List<String> objectClassNames = allObjectClasses.stream().filter(p -> !allowedClasses.contains(p)).map(e -> e.getCanonicalName())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    assertAll(() -> assertTrue(objectClassNames.isEmpty()), () -> {
        if (!objectClassNames.isEmpty()) {
            fail(objectClassNames.toString());
        }
    });
}
```